# Flyway managing multiple schemas with setSchemas method

Tags: multi-tenant, flyway

I'm trying to use flyway to handle multi schemas with identical structures.

I want to centralize the metadatas(infos in version_schema) in a single
schema,
so that it is easy to see and check the metadata which would have been scattered in different schemas.

As the documentation suggests I tried to use the setSchemas() method and listed the schemas I wanted to manage.

Problem is that it just migrates to the first schema on the list and disregards the rest.
The code I used is as below.

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();

flyway.setDataSource(-- Database Info..);
flyway.setSchemas("test1", "test2");
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    flyway.migrate();
}
```

As an alternative I've set the name of each of the schema in the loop as below.

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(-- Database Info..);
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    flyway.setSchemas("test" + i);
    flyway.migrate();
}
```

This works but the metadata is located in each schema.

Is there a way to achieve my goal using the flyway APIs?
I've looked into other questions and saw that I have to prefix the object names accordingly.

Can anyone give me a sample code to implement the solution?